# Ajax sencillo no funciona

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vistas

Uso VS 2017, intento hacer un sencillo ajax pero no funciona

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ajax";
}

<h2>ajax</h2>
<button id="load-btn">Load</button>
<button id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
<img id="loading-image" src="~/Content/ims/ajax-loader.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<div id="message-loading-div">

</div>

<script>
    $('load-btn').click(function (e) {
        $("#loading-image").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Comics/ajaxcall",
            data: null,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#message-loading-div").html(data.message);
                $("#loading-image").hide();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Something went wrong on the controller");
            }
        });
    });

    $('reset-btn').click(function (e) {
        $("#message-loading-div").html('');
    });
</script>
```

[image: Controlador]

Controlador

```
public ActionResult ajax()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ajaxCall()
{
    string message = "Hello  i am from ajax call";
    return Json(new { message });
}
```

Comment: creo que en `$('load-btn').click(function (e){...` falta el `#` de referencia a la id

Comment: @KevinDelva coloca eso como respuesta :D

Comment: Aún no funciona @Kevin

Comment: Hola! podrías agregar mas info ?da error 404 ? error 500?

Comment: Simplemente no hace nada @Kevin

Comment: en chrome abre tu aplicacion y presiona F12 o habre la ventada de developer y en consola revisa que errores tienes antes de presionar el boton de envio.

Answer (score 0):

En la última imagen, parece ser que es tu html ya en el navegador y no veo en dónde esté cargado el script que contiene tú código Ajax, probablemente no se está cargando y por eso no se ejecuta nada.

Por las imágenes que pusiste, veo que lo tienes dentro de la vista ajaxCall. Y supongo, que a su vez, ésta vista se carga dentro de @RenderBody() en la vista compartida _Layout.cshtml. Sin embargo, para que se carguen scripts de las vistas parciales dentro de la vista compartida (_Layout.cshtml), tienes que utilizar la sección de scripts.

Es decir, dentro de tu vista de ajaxCall al final de tu html tienes que encapsular tu script dentro de la sección de scripts:

```
@section scripts{

     <script>
         // Aquí va tu código de ajax
     </script>
}
```

y en tu _Layout.chstml, debes de tener lo siguiente:

```
...
<body>
    ...

     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

De esta manera, tu script de ajax se cargará en la parte final del body del documento final.